# Guake terminal does not drop down with F12 after upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, guake

after a recent upgrade on my local Debian install Guake does not drop down by using `F12`

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.12.0-1-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
     Guake version: 0.8.8-1
```

once I started it manually I can call it with `F12`, but only on the virtual desktop where it was started, as soon as I change do a different desktop I can't call it with `F12` anymore.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, I'm on the 2ond desktop and in the bottom left the guake symbol shows up. I can call the terminal by clicking there with the mouse. But `F12` does not work.

If I start it from a terminal I get the following output:

```
(guake:3387): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.
INFO:guake.guake_app:Logging configuration complete
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py:865: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_window_set_type_hint: assertion '!gtk_widget_get_mapped (GTK_WIDGET (window))' failed
  self.window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py:866: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_window_set_type_hint: assertion '!gtk_widget_get_mapped (GTK_WIDGET (window))' failed
  self.window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py", line 253, in <module>
    exec_main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py", line 250, in exec_main
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: On debian stretch, I had similar problems with guake and Gnome-Wayland. It worked only if the mouse cursor was above an X/Xwayland window. With Gnome-X guake/F12 works fine. It is difficult to set keyboard shortcuts in Wayland.

Comment: @mviereck **wow**, it seems to be the same here. I thought it did not work on the other desktops, but it was because there wasn't any window underneath. With `firefox` in the background it works on any desktop. With `gedit` it doesn't :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue on the official [Guake github-page](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/492#issuecomment-119075514):

You have to go to the Gnome-Applications-Menu and click on the `Keyboard` Symbol.

This will list all the default `Gnome-Keyboard-Shortcuts`.

If you scroll down, click the `+` at the bottom of the page to add a new Shortcut:

```
Name: Guake
Command: guake -t
Shortcut: F12
```

In my case no reboot was needed.

The start of Guake by using this workaround is not very smooth,
but usable...

**from the guake man-page:**

```
-t, --toggle-visibility  
      Toggle the visibility of guake
```

Comment: Note, that this becomes an issue also after update to Ubuntu 19.04, but your workaround works smoothly.

Comment: Thank you! This happens to me on Gnome 3.34.1 on Wayland (Gnome on X.org worked fine).

Comment: At least in my case this works but adds an annoying ~0.5 delay after the keystroke. On X F12 works instantly. The issues [994](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/994) and [1591](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1591#issuecomment-539362287) also seem related