# How do I auto start X application in wayland?

Tags: terminal, x11, wayland, autostart, tilda

I just installed Arch with gnome and wayland. Never used wayland before and I noticed it poses a few problems when I try to run tilda terminal.

I can run tilda using this command:

```
GDK_BACKEND=x11 tilda
```

But, I want to run tilda on autostart. I've tried to solve a couple of ways. The first thing I did was add this line at the start of the tilda.desktop:

```
GDK_BACKEND=x11
```

Then this:

```
env GDK_BACKEND=x11
```

And then this line:

```
env GDK_BACKEND=x11 tilda
```

However, none of those worked. So, i tried to make a really simple bash script calling the tilda terminal and have that run as a startup application

```
#!/bin/bash
GDK_BACKEND=x11 tilda
```

Sadly, this did not work either.

I am confident there should be a way to force tilda to autostart, I'm just not sure exactley how.

Comment: Do you call tilda with a key like shift+F1? Then you can call it only if your mouse cursor is above an Xwayland window, e.g. xterm or firefox. Check whether tilda is running with `ps x | grep tilda`.

Comment: Compare https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388118/guake-terminal-does-not-drop-down-with-f12-after-upgrade